# Probability PDF function question

Tags: probability, density-function

If I have this PDF function, and need to solve for the case that $(P≤0.5)$?

[image]

I undestand that I need to do integer from 0 to 0.5, but how can I get rid of $a$ in that case?

Answer (score 1):

$$1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) \; dx$$
Therefore, $$1=\int_0^{\infty} a\left(2e^{-x}+3e^{-2x}\right) \; dx$$
$$a=\frac{2}{7}$$
Now solve for $P \leq 0.5$.

Comment: thanks!! :) SO I did integer now from 0 to 0.5, took 2/7 out of the brackets and got 0.817.